# VTD-XML: how to get tag name of the current element?

Tags: java, xml, vtd-xml

In the [VTDNav docs](http://goo.gl/w1HLS) I see methods to get value of attrubites, to get text value of the element, but I really can't find, how to get tag name of the current element?

Comment: VN.TOSTRING(VN.GETCURRENTINDEX()); CAN YOU TRY IT?

Comment: Thanks, that works. Add the same as an answer, an I'll surely accept it =)  By the way, thank you, vtd-xml's XPath is extremely faster than Java's DOM implementation, but, in my opninion, documentation of vtd-xml is a bit poor. But, anyway, awesome job, it accelerated my XML-based application a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vn.toRawString(vn.getCurrentIndex())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 vn.toString(vn.getCurrentIndex()
```